# Jquery expression error: expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression

Tags: jquery, jslint

I have a simple code:

```
 _create: function () {
            var self = this;
            $("#Grid").on("click", ".Row", function () {
                $(self).hasClass('Expanded') && $('html, body').animate({
                    scrollTop: $(self).offset().top
                }, 500);
            });
        },
```

On the Jslint I get the following error :

> expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression
>   in  },500)

I thought it might be throwing this error because of the `&&` call but I would prefer to keep it this way.

What's the best approach to corner this?

Comment: why can't you write it like? `if($(self).hasClass('Expanded')){ //that animation code here }`

Comment: `hasClass` function which returns a boolean value used doesn't go along with a finction call

Comment: @ Rajaprabhu Aravindasamy because the code is bundled with a bunch of other js and gets compiled as a min.js file which makes the code to have this form

Comment: The && only makes sense in an if/else if condition. E.g `if(cond1 && cond2){...}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was easy, I was missing the `return` statement.

```
 _create: function () {
            var self = this;
            $("#Grid").on("click", ".Row", function () {
                return $(self).hasClass('Expanded') && $('html, body').animate({
                    scrollTop: $(self).offset().top
                }, 500);
            });
        },
```

Thank you all for helping.

Answer (score 0):

try the following:

```
_create: function () {
            var self = this;
            $("#Grid").on("click", ".Row", function () {
                if ($(self).hasClass('Expanded')){
                    $('html, body').animate({
                        scrollTop: $(self).offset().top
                    }, 500);
                } 
            });
        },
```

Comment: yes that's correct in a way but i stated in the question i would like to keep the &&

Comment: the animate function wont return a boolean value. so you cannot use `&&` along with `hasClass` and `animate`. Moreover you are also not assigning the result of `&&` to any variable which will get used later anywhere